# SSRS : Using URL Access Parameters to printer

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2008-r2

Currently, I am using this method to generate PDF file via SSIS and SSRS.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835(v=sql.105).aspx

[image: Code in SSIS package]

However, I manage to output it to local drive only.

Is it possible to send the PDF file to network printer ?

and do I need to install Adobe Acrobat reader on this machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't need to install adobe acrobat reader if you doesn't need to open this PDF. Export to PDF function is built-in in Report Viewer.
2. For printing, refer this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220412.aspx
3. or write printing code from your backend, send PDF to printer.

Comment: I managed to export PDF using the code attached. Only issue is, I need to send it to printer which could be different network printer depending on what type of reports. Any specific command I need to refer for sending PDF to printer ?

Comment: Example (exactly this function) :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970825/printing-an-external-pdf-document-in-vb-net

Comment: Thanks Marco, I will try it out. Not too sure the code will work in SSIS environment